# pandas converting single row into column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to convert a single column into row and get get corresponding values of that row into its columns.

I tried using pivot table but it gives me the nulls for all other columns where there is no specific corresponding values, but it don't want NaN in the data frame.

I have below data frame df:

```
week          value            
1       1234
1       5678
1       9856
1       5486
1       4569
2       1234
2       5869
2       4865
2       5589
```

I tried

```
df1 = df.pivot(columns='week',values='value')
```

This code returns the data frame with NaN, I want to eliminate all the NaN and get values of each week.the result is shown below. I have added both expected output and the actual output.

The expected result is:

```
1       2
1234   1234   
5678   5869
9856   4865
5486   5589
4569   NaN
```

The actual result is

```
1       2
1234   NaN
5678   NaN
9856   NaN
5486   NaN
4569   1234   
NaN     5869
NaN     4865
NaN     5589
```

I want to remove NaN and align values which belongs to that particular week.

Answer (score 1):

Not the cleanest way, but this get the work done:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'week':[1]*4 + [2]*5 + [3]*7, 'value':np.arange(16)})

df.groupby('week').value.apply(list).apply(pd.Series).T
```

output:

```
+------+-----+-----+------+
| week |  1  |  2  |  3   |
+------+-----+-----+------+
|    0 | 0.0 | 4.0 | 9.0  |
|    1 | 1.0 | 5.0 | 10.0 |
|    2 | 2.0 | 6.0 | 11.0 |
|    3 | 3.0 | 7.0 | 12.0 |
|    4 | NaN | 8.0 | 13.0 |
|    5 | NaN | NaN | 14.0 |
|    6 | NaN | NaN | 15.0 |
+------+-----+-----+------+
```

Comment: Thanks. Weeks are not just 1 and 2 they are multiple. Also the values x1, x2 are not just 4 they might differ from week to week. week 1 might have 1000 values and week 2 might have 500 values and so on

Comment: It still works, will fill the missing 500 values in week 2 with NaN. See edit for details:

Comment: Thanks. What i was to referring to was the values are not sequence of numbers they are random. I have edited the data frame accordingly. Thanks

Comment: Still weeks 1 and 2 both have 4, what do you expect if week 1 has 1000 and week 2 has 500 like you said above?

Comment: That was just a reference, we don't know the numbers of values that we have corresponding to the weeks. If you see the main dataframe week1 has four values, but in actual dataframe it has almost 1000 values and we dont know that number. We are just making that week as a column and list all the values under that week1 and the same for week2 and so on. Thanks.

Comment: Then that’s just what my solution did. It gathers all value of the same week together, regardless of data types.

Comment: my bad i wasn't looking the second line if the code. Thank you very much.